# Get the mean of each column for a 2D PyTorch tensor object

Tags: pytorch

I want to know what is the most simple way to get the mean of the matrix along each column, namely my tensor only has two dimensions with shape (m X n).

For example, if I have a tensor object

```
T = torch.FloatTensor([[2.6, 5], [1.7, 6], [3.2, 7], [2.1, 8]])
```

I want some function that could return a tensor object as following

```
([2.4, 6.5])
```

I know I could do with for loop, but I wonder if there is a PyTorch built-in method that could do this for me, or is there some more elegant way for this purpose.

```
for i in range(T.size(1)):
  mean[i] = torch.mean(T[:, i])
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the doc on [`torch.mean`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.10.0/generated/torch.mean.html#torch.mean).
It has an optional parameter `dim`:

> `dim` (`int` or tuple of `int`s) – the dimension or dimensions to reduce.

In your case:

```py
T.mean(dim=0)
```

Will give you the mean along the first dim.

Note that many other "reduction" operations in pytorch (and in [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy)) also have this option to reduce along a specific dimension only (e.g., `std`, `sum` etc.).